# Add VUI parameters to h.264 post encode

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, mpeg-dash, libx264

Apparently ffmpeg/libx264 doesn't add these VUI parameters and this is causing issues with my decoder. Avidemux 2.5 does (2.6 does not) but I would very much like to avoid preparing/re-encoding the hundreds of files.

The VUI parameters I am looking to add are:

- max_num_reorder_frames=0
- bitstream_restriction_flag=1

Is anyone aware of any tools that could accomplish this without re-encoding? If this is something that would need to be custom written, where would be a good place to find the right person?

Thanks,
Dustin

Comment: Not aware of a tool that does this, but you may be able to [augment](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=152419) the filter here to do this.

Comment: @Mulvya Have you found where the source files are for this filter?

Comment: This looks to be it --> https://svn.code.sf.net/p/direct264/code/Patches/ffmpeg_git_32732.patch . Scroll down to `diff --git a/libavcodec/h264_changesps_bsf.c b/libavcodec/h264_changesps_bsf.c`

Comment: If you modify this, would you mind releasing it as a patch?